# Databinding a user control within an itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

I have a UserControl that has a ViewModel containing an instance of my own custom class, call it Person. This ViewModel is set as the DataContext of the control. I am wanting to use this control in my main window which has, in its ViewModel a List of type Person called People. I am calling the control in my xaml like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <userControls:PersonDetails />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Properties within the control are bound in this manner.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Name}" />
```

When I run I am getting the correct number of Controls for the amount of People in the list but no details are populated. I know I am doing something simple wrong but can't find it. Please help.

EDIT:

My UserControl xaml looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AddressBook.UserControls.PersonDetails"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AddressBook.UserControls"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AddressBook.ViewModels"
         xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:AddressBook.Models"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="1000">    

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailHeader}" Text="Person Name:" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailValue}" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Person.Name,
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailHeader}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Text="Street Address:" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailValue}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Person.StreetAddress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailHeader}" Grid.Row="2" Text="Town:" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PeronDetailValue}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Person.Town, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailHeader}" Grid.Row="3" Text="County:" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailValue}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Person.County, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailHeader}" Grid.Row="4" Text="Postcode:" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailValue}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Person.Postcode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailHeader}" Grid.Row="5" Text="Phone:" />

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonDetailValue}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding Person.Phone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Content="Click" Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}" />

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

UserControl ViewModel:

```
public class PersonDetailsViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public Command ButtonClickCommand { get; } 

    public PersonDetailsViewModel()
    {
        ButtonClickCommand = new Command(ButtonClick);
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

UserControl.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class PersonDetails : UserControl
{
    public PersonDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Person.cs

```
public class Person : BaseModel
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
```

etc....

MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        PopulatePeople();
    }
}
```

Comment: Listen to data context changed event for user control and check what data context you are getting. Whether it is the right one that you wanted i.e. your Person class ?

Comment: Ash - no binding errors in Output.

Comment: Silvermind - Thank you but this did not work.

Versatile - The DataContextChanged event is not even firing so it clearly is not getting set at all.

Comment: Can you show your user control?

Comment: What objects are in `People`? Do they have a `Person` property? Or is `Person` their type? If `Person` is the name of the class rather than the name of a property of the class, try `Text="{Binding Name}"` in the `TextBlock`.

Comment: Get rid of `<UserControl.DataContext>` in your UserControl. Kill it with fire. What that does is create a new empty `PersonDetailsViewModel` instance for each instance of your usercontrol, *which will hide* the `DataContext` it inherited from the `DataTemplate`. BTW @Silvermind is mistaken about that; I just checked to be sure.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks. I'm now a step closer. The DataContextChanged property is now firing and has the correct context. However the data still doesn't populate and there appears to be some kind of disconnect. For example I have a Button in the Control bound to a command in the ViewModel. Clicking the button no longer fires the command.

Comment: @PaulKnight Show me what the code looks like now. Including the XAML.

Comment: @EdPlunkett code samples edited!

Comment: Can you include the entire XAML for the user control. the entire .xaml.cs for the user control, the viewmodel where `People` is defined, and the definition of the `Person` class?

Comment: @EdPlunkett updated again.

Comment: @PaulKnight Thanks, all is now clear (at least I think so!)

Comment: @Silvermind User controls absolutely do inherit the DataContext.  I'm not sure where you're getting that from.

Comment: BTW @PaulKnight, when you're experiencing issues with bindings at runtime, easiest way to debug them is to use Snoop.

Comment: @Will Snoop????

Comment: Use a search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I understand why you were creating the `PersonDetailsViewModel` in the `UserControl` XAML, and what the problem was with the command.

The simplest way to fix this is to make `MainViewModel.People` a collection of `PersonDetailsViewModel` instead of `Person`. That's what I'd do.

But if you want to leave `MainViewModel.People` as it is, while still using `PersonDetailsViewModel` inside your `UserControl`, that makes sense to me. You could do this:

.xaml

```
<UserControl 
     x:Class="AddressBook.UserControls.PersonDetails"
     DataContextChanged="PersonDetails_DataContextChanged"

     ...etc...

     >

    <!-- Give the Grid a name... -->
    <Grid x:Name="OuterGrid">
```

.xaml.cs

```
public PersonDetails()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void PersonDetails_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //  ...so we can give the Grid a different DataContext
    OuterGrid.DataContext = new PersonDetailsViewModel { 
        Person = (Person)this.DataContext
    };
}
```

Now it will inherit a `Person` for its `DataContext`, but internally it will use a `PersonDetailsViewModel` based on that `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you are trying to do.
If you only wish to display some carac of every Person present in your People List you could do :

```
     <Grid>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                                    </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

That will bind you Text on the Name property of each element of your list, so on the name of each Person of your list.
As your ItemsSource is already bound to People, the Binding of your Items is already on each Person of your List, so you should call your properties directly as {Binding Name} and not {Binding Person.Name}

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there are other fields to display within the user control like a contact card, I just omitted them because none of them are showing and are all bound in the same way.

Comment: Is your UserControl another windows that you populate with the selected Person ? Or is it a grid that contains at all time all your Persons and their information ?

Comment: I've edited my answer so it can correspond to as much field as you want

Comment: it populates with just one person.

Comment: Did you make sure to bind on People and not Person ?
In my sample test it shows me every items of my binded List